# ReactJS Cannot find babel-preset-es2015 on npm start

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I got some test of ReactJS and Here's my Code:

.babelrc

```
{
     { "presets": [ [ "es2015", { "modules": false } ] ] }
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return ( <div> <h1> Hello World </h1> </div> );
    }
}
export default App;
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>React App</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src='index_bundle.js'></script>
</body>

</html>
```

main.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.js';

ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('app'));
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "reactapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
        "build": "webpack --mode production"
    },
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "gulp-babel": "^8.0.0",
        "react": "^16.7.0",
        "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
        "webpack": "^4.28.4",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.2.3",
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
        "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0"
    }
}
```

Node.js Version: `6.4.1`

babel core version: `7.2.2`

The problem is, when i hit `npm start` it brings me an error and the page displayed empty:

> ERROR in ./main.js
>       Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
>       Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-es2015'

Tried some solutions but the error still exists.

Comment: `babel-preset-es2015` is deprecated. Use `babel-preset-env` instead.

Answer (score 7):

ES2015 is deprecated, change on your `webpackconfig.js` to

```
module: {
      rules: [
         {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
               presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
            }
         }
      ]
   },
```

And set .babelrc to:

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env"]
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

**install**

```
npm install --save babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread
npm install --save babel-preset-env
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
    "presets":[
      "env","es2015", "react"
    ],

  "plugins": [
    "react-hot-loader/babel", "transform-object-rest-spread"
  ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0"
    "webpack": "^4.28.4",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @ShaliniSentiya but  the error still exists.

Comment: plz find the updated post answer and change package.json file like post

Answer (score 0):

The `es20**-presets` are deprecated, so pls switch to `@babel/preset-env.`

Install

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-env
```

Then add the preset to your .babelrc

```
{
    presets: ["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MyTwoCents trying this solution but the error still the same.

Comment: I have this config yet it's still asking for `babel-preset-es2015`